# Error creating Trigger delete as soon as the INSERT Query is executed

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a trigger to test my application such that as soon as a row is inserted delete it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triger1 AFTER INSERT ON tableA
 DELETE from tableA where columnA = new.coulmnA;
```

But it is throwing me error saying 'DELETE' (delete) is not a valid input at this position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MySQL trigger doesn't work, simple sintax, not complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517731/my-mysql-trigger-doesnt-work-simple-sintax-not-complicated)

Comment: Self referencing trigger is not allowed in MySQL. You can't update the same table on which trigger is defined.

Comment: @e4c5, is it really duplicate of that question; bit in doubt

Comment: @rahul, your comment is a summary of the upvoted answer on that question. So yes, it's a duplicate

Comment: @e4c5, Ahh!! Yes right. it's a duplicate indeed.

Comment: Could your problem be solved with my post or the linked topic?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot delete rows** from the **same table** where you create you **TRIGGER**. This would create a deadlock.

That is because **MYSQL** locks the table on an `INSERT` operation.

Comment: Umm... not exactly, same is allowed in SQL Server

Comment: Then shouldn't it behave same way in other RDBMS as well?

Comment: See this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90234. It would be nice if it does behave the same way, but it obviously doesn't