# MySql insert trigger outputs NULL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to have an insert trigger to achieve incremental inserts. I have one column "row_hash" to record the MD5 of each row(here I use MD5 of column `name` and `category`). If the new record has the same hash value, the trigger should skip insert, otherwise it allows the insert.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test_trigger;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON test_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table WHERE row_hash = MD5(CONCAT_WS('', new.name, new.category))) < 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO test_table(_id, name, category, row_hash) VALUES (new._id, new.name, new.category, MD5(CONCAT_WS('', new.name, new.category)));
    END IF;
END$$
```

Here is the test table:

```
create table test_table(_id varchar(10) primary key, name varchar(10), category varchar(2), row_hash char(32));
```

When I insert one record, it outputs NULL on the `row_hash` column.

```
insert into test_table(_id, name, category) values('12344', 'dafas', 'A');

'12344','dafas','A',NULL
```

Can you tell me where I did it wrong on the trigger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MySQL trigger doesn't work, simple sintax, not complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517731/my-mysql-trigger-doesnt-work-simple-sintax-not-complicated)

Comment: @e4c5, that is not a duplicate of this question. They have one thing in common—MySQL triggers—but the problem described is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the row being inserted, you don't need to use an `INSERT` to the same table. Just `SET NEW.row_hash` values.

If you want to abort an insert, you'll have to use a [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html).

But overall, it appears that what you're doing shouldn't require a conditional INSERT in the trigger at all. Just a `UNIQUE` constraint on name, category. In the trigger, just make sure the `row_hash` is set correctly, then the constraint will take care of aborting if there's a duplicate.

*edit:* Changed the unique key to use only the row_hash column, as you suggested.

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD UNIQUE KEY (row_hash);

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.row_hash = MD5(CONCAT_WS('', name, category));
```

Comment: Good point! I followed your idea to add a unique key on row_hash because I have many columns to check in real cases. Here is the minor change on your concat_ws with new.name and new.category. Big thanks!

`CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON test_table 
FOR EACH ROW SET new.row_hash = MD5(CONCAT_WS('', new.name, new.category));`

Comment: Yep, that's it! You should make a trigger run `BEFORE UPDATE` too, to do the same thing in case one of the columns in the hash-key set of columns changes.

Comment: One nice thing about simpler triggers is that you don't need to worry about `DELIMITER` if your trigger body is a single statement. :-)