# How to avoid recurive trigger calls with INSERT trigger also calling INSERT?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I'm new to triggers and all of these procedures stuff. I'm trying to create a simple AFTER INSERT trigger which will duplicate a `friendship` but swap user_id's, so both users have one. Here's the structure:

[image]

And here's my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `combat`.`friendship_insert_trigger` AFTER INSERT
    ON `combat`.`friendships`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       DECLARE userID INT;
       DECLARE friendID INT;

       SET userID = NEW.friend_id;
       SET friendID = NEW.user_id;

       INSERT INTO friendships VALUES(userID, friendID, NEW.status);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see, it calls INSERT with swapped values.

**Is there any way to 'tell' the new insert statement to not call the trigger again?** 
I'm using `SQLyogg` and `Ubuntu 16 Mysql`

An example:
I insert a friendship with user_id = 1, friend_id = 2 and status = 0.
It should also insert a friendship with user_id = 2, friend_id = 1 and status = 0;

Comment: Let me play oracle for a bit - you haven't created this trigger yet and you haven't tested that the scenario you envisioned will even happen, right? :)

Comment: "Can't update table 'friendships' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." :D Got you!

Comment: Yep, you got it now :) you'll have to come up with something else to duplicate rows, and there's nothing wrong with issuing 2 queries. Try to avoid too much "magic" using triggers / stored procedures / events.

Comment: There's no way to tell it not to call the trigger again. That's why a trigger isn't allowed to modify the same table.

Comment: Yeah, realized that after reading some answers. Will make a 'double REPLACE' stmt and it should do. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MySQL trigger doesn't work, simple sintax, not complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517731/my-mysql-trigger-doesnt-work-simple-sintax-not-complicated)