# MySQL trigger Error: 1442

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

DB: MySQL

Using: MySQL Workbench

I am currently working on a project for class where we have to design a airport website in which users can login/register and buy tickets for various flights offered. After working on the project for some time I realized that my trigger is not working.

I receive the error: `Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'reservation' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

I stumbled upon this error by trying to insert a reservation before creating the form for users to select and buy tickets. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my database, insert command use, and also my trigger code. Any help would be much appreciated because I am at wits end trying to figure this out for hours.

Insert command: http://pastebin.com/tyBPWNDd

Entire DB and Trigger in question: http://pastebin.com/BvUj1NdH

**Solved:** thanks to all helpers I was able to identify my problem which was using recursive triggers when MySQL does not support them. I solved my problem by removing the recursive code and letting my website backend handle the current_date set instead of the trigger. I will post the fixed trigger shortly.

Comment: A trigger can't modify the table which caused it to be executed.  You need to rearrange your logic so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank-you! You have been a great help

Comment: Glad to be useful to you, but maybe you should comment on how you resolved the problem so that this question might be more helpful to others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MySQL trigger doesn't work, simple sintax, not complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517731/my-mysql-trigger-doesnt-work-simple-sintax-not-complicated)

Comment: @timbiegeleisen I posted a solved section in my original post just now. I will post the changed sql trigger as well shortly. Thank you once again for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the error is self explanatory. You are trying to create a recursive trigger which is not supported in `MySQL` as can be seen in your posted code

```
Create Trigger reservation_all
    after insert on Reservation
    for each row
    begin
        update Reservation
```

Check [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) on same for more infromation. Quoting from that

> - Stored functions cannot be used recursively.
> - A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already       being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the 
>     function or trigger.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense now and I cannot believe I missed something like this. You are a great help Rahul.