# MySQL Delete on Trigger in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Can I delete rows in a table when calling a trigger on it?

such as:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3);
```

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `db`.`trig_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if (new.val1 > (select val1 from table1 where val2 = new.val2 limit 1))
    delete from table1 where val2 = new.val2;
end if;
END
```

This is so that I only keep the maximum `val1` per `val2`.

I have done this in PostgreSQL but I cannot find a way to accomplish in MySQL.

Comment: You categorically cannot do this in MySQL, because MySQL does not allow recursive triggers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MySQL trigger doesn't work, simple syntax, not complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517731/my-mysql-trigger-doesnt-work-simple-syntax-not-complicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MySQL does not allow this, see [Restrictions on Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions)

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

If `col2` is non-null, and you want to keep only one row (and not several rows that might have the same maximum value), you can achieve the same result by using a unique index on `col2`, e.g. making it your primary key, and then use

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3)
values (val1, val2, val3)
on duplicate key update 
   col3 = case when col1 >= values(col1) then col3 else values(col3) end,
   col1 = greatest(values(col1), col1);
```

to insert your values (and no trigger).

This will keep at most one row per `col2`, and updating it with the new value if the new row has a higher value for `col1`. If `col1` can be `null`, use `coalesce` in the comparisons. (If `col2` can be `null`, this method will not work, because it would not violate the unique constraint.)

Comment: can I use a trigger to delete row of the same table on which the trigger is created in sql developer ? The idea is to create a delete record column with True false values. #sqldeveloper

Comment: @Sandeep In MySQL (just to make sure, since you mention sql developer), you cannot do any changes to any row in the same table except the currently inserted/updated/deleted single row, and you also cannot change e.g. an insert into a delete or something. Not exactly sure what you mean by *"The idea is to create a delete record column"*, but if you want to insert a row that tells the trigger to delete another row in the same table, that's not possible. (You may want to ask a new question describing your idea/task though, there might be alternatives.)

Comment: thank you. My ideas is to delete the current updated/ inserted row where deleterow column = 'True'. say I updated a row and changed its delete row column value to 'True'. I want this row to be automatically deleted by trigger. How can I do that.

Comment: @Sandeep You cannot do that with MySQL. Nevertheless, please add a new question for this (and/or check if it already exists), the comment section is not the correct place place to ask a different question (your problem is a bit different from what the answer or the original question is about, and there might be other ways to solve your problem).

Comment: yes I will create a new question for this problem. But I think you have answered my query. My apologies for using this comment section as a way to get my answer. 
Thanks a lot.