# MySQL Error 1442 Using 2 triggers to update a field of 2 tables on 2 different databases

Tags: mysql, triggers, synchronization

I am trying to get the quantity field synchronized in 2 tables on 2 different databases using triggers.

I found some examples and tried to adapt them to this requirement why not success and showing this error...

> `#1442` - Can't update table 'oc_product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

... when trying to perfom this query:

```
UPDATE `db`.`oc_product` SET `quantity` = '220' WHERE `oc_product`.`product_id` = 50
```

Trigger for db2, table stock:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS t1_ai &&

CREATE TRIGGER t1_ai BEFORE UPDATE ON stock FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF @__disable_trigger_t1t2 = 1 THEN
    SET @__disable_trigger_t1t2 = NULL;
  ELSE
    SET @__disable_trigger_t1t2 = 1;
    -- trigger logic goes in here
    UPDATE `db1`.oc_product 
    SET  `quantity` = NEW.quantity 
    WHERE SKU = NEW.SKU;
  END IF;
END &&
```

Trigger for db1, table oc_product:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS t2_ai &&

CREATE TRIGGER t2_ai BEFORE UPDATE ON oc_product  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF @__disable_trigger_t1t2 = 1 THEN
    SET @__disable_trigger_t1t2 = NULL;
  ELSE
    SET @__disable_trigger_t1t2 = 1;
    -- trigger logic goes in here
    UPDATE `db2`.stock 
    SET  `quantity` = NEW.quantity 
    WHERE SKU = NEW.SKU; 
  END IF;
END &&
```

Any idea how to fix that error?

Extra information:
If I perfom this query for the stock table on db2:

```
UPDATE `db2`.`stock` SET `quantity` = '220' WHERE `stock`.`id` = 7631;
```

Then the trigger t1_ai do the job, but not vice-versa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My MySQL trigger doesn't work, simple syntax, not complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517731/my-mysql-trigger-doesnt-work-simple-syntax-not-complicated)

Comment: I do not think so, why the other trigger does not do the job? Which is the reason?

Comment: You have one trigger that fires anotehr which updates one of the tables you are not allowed to modify. In this case the table named stock

Comment: Which is the best method to acomplish this? I implemented these triggers to get both updated, what do you suggest?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause**: You cannot update/delete/insert to a table (stock) where the trigger is invoked:

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Doing so will generate Error 1442:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'oc_product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

What is happening here, `UPDATE` on `stock` table fires the first trigger '`t1_ai`' which in it's SQL attempts to update the `oc_product` table, which has a trigger '`t1_ai`' which attempts an update/change back on the `stock` table.
So, as mentioned above you:

> it is not permitted to **modify** a table that is already being **used** (for
>   **reading** or **writing**)

For this whole flow (cascading triggers) the `stock` is still in use (hence locked for further read or write) i.e. the first table update where these cascading triggers got fired.

---

**Suggestion**:
Try implementing a procedure and call it via your application.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by implementing your suggestion